# Get newly created subsite name and url in power automate flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer, power-automate, microsoft-flow

Could you please help how to get the newly created sub sites name and their urls, of sitecollection based on the date passed ? If i pass today's date, it should display the list of sub sites and their URL's created today.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get subsites in Flow, you will need to make a http request call. The endpoint will be like below:

```
https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/webs?$select=title,ServerRelativeUrl,Created&$orderby=Created%20desc
```

The action is like this:
[image]

You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-all-site-collections-of-office-365-tenant-in-ms-flow/) to list all subsites with required properties. And add actions you need in the flow.